# how to use rest-assured for integration tests on my WS without modyfing database state?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, integration-testing, rest-assured

I'm currently developping a REST Web service with Spring MVC.

And I am struggling to find the best way to do integration tests on my WS.

First solution : using rest-assured

- Advantage : fluent api, really easy to use with its cool DSL
- Drawback : when i perform POST or PUT requests on my WS, the state of my database is modified, and next tests are corrupted.

Second solution : unit test the controllers and perform integration tests at the service level separately

- Advantage : i can control the state of my database, using Spring Test Framework and perform rollback after each test
- Disadvantage : i do not perform end-to-end integration tests anymore.

Question : how can i use rest-assured to do integration tests without modifying the state of my database ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you delete the rest assured doubles and redirects before every test and set them up fresh for the test?

```
    RestClient.delete "#{RestAssured::Server.address}/redirects/all"
    RestClient.delete "#{RestAssured::Server.address}/doubles/all"
```

Or alternatively you can use different doubles for the GET and POST/PUT calls to the rest assured and use the redirects in between these calls.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, your request makes sense as you state it.

RestAssured is just a framework to support you with testing. You can also write unit tests, that do the equivalent of PUT and DELETE (basically the internal implementations), which then modify the database state.

Or you can only issue HEAD and GET requests with RestAssured and not modify the database state by this.

Both of the options will only test parts of the code path if you leave any updates out, so your issue is orthogonal to the selection of RestAssured or hand written unit tests.

Of course you can mock your backend away, but either the mocks are trivial and you don't gain any insight. Or they are complex and you will need separate tests to assure that the mock objects to what you think they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform integration tests on a REST Spring MVC Web Service, the SpringSource team has provided a new library called spring-test-mvc, which is now integrate to spring-test.

http://blog.springsource.org/2012/11/12/spring-framework-3-2-rc1-spring-mvc-test-framework/

For my special purpose, it is more adapted than Rest-Assured.